# Commutator of operator having a normal dilatation

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A, B \in B(H)$,  the Banach algebra of all bounded linear operators acting on an infinite dimensional complex Hilbert space $H$. Assume that 
$$AB=BA$$ and
$$ A=U^{*}NU, $$ where $U$ is an unitary operator and $N$ is a normal operator.
 Do we have $$ BU=UB $$ and $$ BN=NB .$$

I tried to produce a counterexample in the finite dimensional case but.....

Comment: $A$ commutes with $A$. Does $AU=UA$ and $AN=NA$?

Comment: Since $B$ commuts with $A$, we ask if $B$ commuts with $U$ and $N$.